# What's the conventional way to annotate globals in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, lint

There's some convention for writing about globals in JS that looks something like `/* globals: foo, _ */` placed at the beginning of the file, but I can't remember it for the life of me. It's a miserable thing to search for, too.

The one other thing I can remember about it is that it was useful for silencing related linter errors.

Comment: Just check the docs of the specific linter you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to tell JSLint about globals is to use the `globals` directive. For example:

```
/*globals globalFunction, anotherGlobal, oneMore */
```

Comment: ...that is, if you use `global` instead of `globals`